# How to implement multiple reducers in a single MapReduce Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I'm having a huge data set and I need to perform different functions for the same data.
    I would like to have four output files. Since four operations are different, can I use four *partitioners* and four *reducers* to implement the same ? Is it possible or should I need to write four jobs to perform this ?  Please help me !

Comment: What do you mean by making four partitioners here sachin?

Comment: I'm a beginner and i have learned that no.of reducers=num.of partitoners. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks !

Comment: Number of reducers can be set by your side. Partitioner is always 1, according to my understanding. So if you want 4 part files you can set the number of reducers to 4.

Comment: for performing different operations ideally you should have different jobs.

Comment: I need four outputs from the same dataset. The processing of the dataset in four cases are different. But i have some of the outputs in common. So should i need four Jobs or can i solve it with a single Job. I'm not experienced in Hadoop so I just wanted to know the ideal way.

Comment: Its always preferred to have multiple jobs for multiple functionalities.

Comment: @aviral: It shares some common features and operates on the same dataset. That's why I raised this query. Anyways Thanks for your response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72116/discussion-between-aviral-and-sachin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Approach**

I think you should implement the code in a unique reduce method, and emit n keys depending the process performed. For example: You implement A,B,C and D techiniques, then, in your mapper you could implement this (pseudo-code):

```
dataA = ProcessA(key,value)
context.write("A", dataA)
dataB = ProcessB(key,value)
context.write("B", dataB)
dataC = ProcessC(key,value)
context.write("C", dataC)
dataD = ProcessD(key,value)
context.write("D", dataD)
```

You should be careful about data types of output. Also, the output key could be more complex.

**Second Approach**

You could generate N MapReduce applications in the same java project, and then you re-use the Map, and develop N reducers.

In `job.setReducerClass` in each main class you set each Reducer. The Map will be the same.

Comment: I'm more interested in the second approach. But how to implement N map reduce applications with the same class ? Can you give an example of how to generate N map-reduce applications in same project each with the same mapper and different reducer implementations. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for self-promote: [Here](https://github.com/tomasdelvechio/YarnExamples) I have a project, where I developed some MapReduce Applications. The code is tested for Hadoop 2.5.0. If you import the classes to each App, you could re-use Map class, Reduce class, Combiner class.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify number of reducers in your MapReduce
job config. The default partitioner will distribute data to reducers based on hash of key modulus number of specified reducers.

To override behavior of default partitioner, you can implement your own custom partitioner specifying how your data should get across to the reducers.

---Edit to answer questions in the comments section---

***How can i specify more than one reducer class in the Map-reduce driver***

To set number of reducers, in job conf you can set it like below -

```
int numReducers = /*number of reducers you want*/;
job.setNumReduceTasks(numReducers);
```

***Whether I should write four different Jobs for this. Or can I do this with a single Job***

Hadoop MR jobs are I/O intensive, in your MR job design you should work on minimizing the I/O and parallel processing as much possible.

If your reducers need same input for generating all 4 outputs, it will be better to keep single job, but another consideration can be skewness of data for either output.
For example output1 has more processing time + most of incoming data is likely to be processed for output1.
If you have scenerio like time taken to process output1 is much higher then total time taken to process output2 + output3 + output4, then you should considering splitting processing of output1 in multiple steps.

However if we consider all 4 outouts have more or less equal processing times and consumes same data throughout,
It will be better to have some conditional processing logic in the reducer and let your custom partioner decide which data goes to which reducer.

Your custom partioner can have some check like this incoming data qualifies to be contributing to "GC content" so let it got to Reducer 3.
But if your incoming data needs to be processed for more then one output/distribution use conditional processing and to write multiple output files from same reducer use "MultipleOutputs".
You can google it up and find usage examples, it lets you write output to multiple folders/files at the same time from within a Mapper or Reducer.

Comment: But in that case also, I need to write different implementations for different reducers. How can i specify more than one reducer class in the Map-reduce driver ?

Comment: Whether I should write four different Jobs for this. Or can I do this with a single Job ?

Comment: It will be lot better if you provide a sample input/output or more details of what you want to achieve, you can easily implement conditional processing logic if you want to use single job, else you can write multiple jobs....all depends on what and how you want to do it

Comment: I have a Genome sequence data and want to perform some QC analysis on the same. I want to extract useful information from every line of it. And my outputs will be like Base Distribution,Quality Distribution,GC content and Some stats of the data. Some outputs are common here. So should i need to process the same input four times with four Jobs or is there a way to process it with a single Job ?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop let's you specify the number of reducer tasks from the job driver **job.setNumReduceTasks(num_reducers);**. Since you want four outputs, you would specify `int num_reducers = 4;` Here's an example driver class.

```
public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Run NB Count");

        job.setJarByClass(NB_train_hadoop.class);
        // set mappers, reducers, other stuff
        job.setNumReduceTasks(num_reducers);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

While this is handy, you have to understand that there is an optimal number of reducers you can choose which is dependent on the number of nodes in your cluster.

For example, running 4 Amazon m3.xlarge instances (1 master, 3 slaves, and 4 cores an instance), has the following relationship between wall time and number of reducer tasks used in the MapReduce job. You can see that more isn't necessarily better and if you use too many, well then you might as well crunch your data with your mother's hair curler because it would be faster that way.

[image]

Hope this is helpful!!